# Cannot create properties for simple Objective-C object

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong here? I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, but for the life of me this code doesn't look wrong.

### Update:

It reproduces consistently on my machine

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look wrong to me either. Can't reproduce. Can you?

Comment: I've restarted Xcode and restarted my whole machine and the issue hasn't gone away. I can try to create a new file, copy/paste the code, and see what happens.

Comment: I just created a new file (`BFSite2.h`), copied the code in, and tried to build -- same error (I can post the screenshot)

Comment: I'm going to guess there is an invisible character at the end of those lines. Don't copy and paste: delete the lines and retype them.

Comment: I sure wish you would stop showing pictures of code.

Comment: @matt The purpose of the pictures is to demonstrate 1. That the code is not syntax highlighting, 2. That the error is legitimately occurring in Xcode, 3. Which lines are affected. Without the pictures I dont' think you would have suggested an invisible character as a culprit (if I just copied in code, you'd probably never suspect such a thing)

Comment: On the contrary, if you copied and pasted the text, the invisible character would be present and I'd be able to detect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess there is an invisible character somewhere in those lines. For example I can reproduce the error message by pasting in a Unicode Backspace character `(U+0008)`.

Comment: Just adding, you could go to the Editor menu and enable "Show Invisibles" to see, well, invisible characters.

Comment: @AlejandroIván No, that doesn't show this kind of character. Xcode is not the place to find them. BBEdit is, though.

Comment: Turns out I had a `DATA LINK ESCAPE` character before the `@property` on those lines. "Show Invisibles" unfortunately does not display it.

Comment: Well I was close, that’s `U+0010`.